# Elasticsearch cluster in AWS ECS

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to create an elasticsearch cluster in AWS ECS but i'm getting the warn  `"message": "master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes`. My elasticsearch.yml and task definition are the same for all nodes. How can i differentiate between the master and the other nodes ? Should i have a separate elasticsearch.yml/task definition for master node ?

My elasticsearch.yml :

```
cluster.name: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
bootstrap.memory_lock: false
network.host: 0.0.0.0
network.publish_host: _ec2:privateIp_
transport.publish_host: _ec2:privateIp_
discovery.seed_providers: ec2
discovery.ec2.tag.project: xxxxxxx-elasticsearch
discovery.ec2.endpoint: ec2.${REGION}.amazonaws.com
s3.client.default.endpoint: s3.${REGION}.amazonaws.com
cloud.node.auto_attributes: true
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes: aws_availability_zone
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

Comment: What is your `elasticsearch.yml` ? Update your question with it.

Comment: ```elasticsearch.yml``` updated in the question

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the similar problem as well. Firstly, You need to create a initial cluster and make it ready to form a cluster. It is possible to start by using a inital node configuration on elasticsearch.yml. The solution I am using is to host on one ECS instance running with one elasticsearch docker container (As elasticsearch requires good amount of memory)

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes: '<<INITIAL_NODE_IPADDRESS>>'
```

This above configuration kickstarts the cluster that means elasticsearch is ready to join the nodes. In the next step Add the below configuration

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes: [<<MASTER_NODE_IPADDRESS>>,<<INITIAL_NODE_IPADDRESS>>]
discovery.seed_hosts: [<<MASTER_NODE_IPADDRESS>>,<<INITIAL_NODE_IPADDRESS>>]
```

Then you can add as many number of data nodes as you want. This depends on how much data you have.

Note: The IPADDRESS are from different nodes so use AWS SSM Parameter store to store IP securely and use engtrypoint.sh to get those and update the elasticsearch.yml file dynamically when you are building the docker images.

I hope this will solve the problem.

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/master-not-discovered-yet-this-node-has-not-previously-joined-a-bootstrapped-v7-cluster/176304/39

Follow this thread.